# Search in AutoHotkey for a window title that contains a string, but does not contain another string

Tags: autohotkey

I have a script that activates sublime text window:

```
#s::
IfWinExist ,Sublime
    {
    ifWinActive
        {
        WinActivatebottom ,Sublime
    }
    else
    {
        WinActivate
    }
    return
}
```

If there are many windows of sublime text it shows them one after another (each time I press it shows the next window).

**My question is:** There is one project (moshe.project), That I don't want to show. How I add an expection to it

For example: `ifWinExists, Sublime !moshe`

Answer (score 1):

```
 ; autoexecute section:
SetTitleMatchMode, 2
; GroupAdd, GroupName, WinTitle, WinText, Label, ExcludeTitle
GroupAdd, Sublime_group, Sublime,,,moshe
     return   ; end of autoexecute section


#IfWinExist, ahk_group Sublime_group

#s::
IfWinNotActive, ahk_group Sublime_group
    GroupActivate, Sublime_group, R  ; activates the newest window (the one most recently active)
else
    GroupActivate, Sublime_group  ; activates the oldest window
Return

#IfWinExist
```

EDIT:
Use Window Spy to find the exact title of the window you want exclude.

EDIT2:  I modified the code to catch all windows that have "sublime" in the title, and don't have "moshe" in the title.